# CD dust cover auf Deutsch

Tags: meaning, english-to-german, meaning-in-context

Wie nennt man im Deutschen eine **Pappabdeckung einer CD**?
Auf Englisch nennt man sie *a dust cover*. Ich habe gegoogelt, aber ich denke, dass der *Staubschutz einer CD* was anderes ist.

Wie sagt man: *the dust cover has minor scratches*?
Kann ich das englisches Wort benutzen? z.B:

> Der Dust cover weist ein paar leichte Kratzer auf.

Wenn ja, wie soll ich das Wort schreiben?
Dustcover, Dust cover, Dust-cover, Dust-Cover?

[image: CD dust cover]

Comment: Verleger sagen *Schuber*. Normale Benutzer sagen meist einfach *Hülle*, auch wenn das Mehrdeutigkeit verursacht, wenn sowohl Papp- als auch Plastikhülle mitgeliefert wurden.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bei Büchern heißt das [Schuber](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schuber). Also:

> der [CD]-Schuber

Answer (score 1):

Das ist im einfachsten Falle eine

> CD-Hülle

Wenn klar sein soll, dass sie nicht aus Plastik ist, könnte es eine

> CD-Hülle aus Pappe

sein. Wenn aber innen auch noch so eine Kunststoff-Hülle ist (wie das dem Bild nach wohl der Fall ist), würde ich sagen:

> Der Umschlag aus Pappe hat ein paar Kratzer, die Plastikhülle innen ist aber wie neu.

Und zwar würde ich hier "Umschlag" sagen, weil das Wort "Hülle" dann ja schon bei der Plastikhülle verwendet wird, und zweimall "Hülle" für dann doch verschiedene Dinge möchte man in einem Satz nicht zusammenbringen.

Comment: Danke, aber hiere ist nicht eine CD-Hülle gemeint. CD-Hüllen sind normalerweise eine Jewelcase oder eine Papphülle. Diese Wörter sind mir bekannt ;-) Ich interessiere mich nur an der Pappabdeckung (Dust-cover). Ich wundere mich ob es im Deutschen ein besonderes Wort gibt.

Comment: Sieht man denn nun deinen *dust cover* auf dem Foto? Dafür würde mein *Umschlag aus Pappe* nämlich schon passen. Oder auch in der Variante *Schutzumschlag*, auch wenn das ein bisschen tautologisch ist. - "Dust-Cover" in allen Varianten solltest du aber möglichst nicht writen, weil du sonst in die Danger läufst, allzu sehr in English zu speaken.